# Why are my menu items not in the center(without using flexbox)?

Tags: html, css

I know there are innumerable topics on the subject of centering text horizontally. But I used the search function and tried the answers. It did not work though.

I tried margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto, text-align: center etc. for the class nav-center. That did not work.

**I want the Lorem Ipsum in the Center of the Navbar.**

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```css
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/************************************************************* styles.css ***************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:General Settings *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:General Settings  *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navigation > div {
  height:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/* *** START: Nav-Logo *** */
nav div.nav-logo img {
  height: 3rem;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left:2rem;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Logo *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Center *** */
nav .nav-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

nav .nav-center > ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Center *** */


/* *** START: Nav-End *** */
div.nav-end {
  float:right;
}
/* *** END: Nav-End *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Items *** */
div.nav-items ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.nav-items ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

div.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

div.nav-items a:link {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:visited {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:hover,
div.nav-items a:active {
  color:#e5e5e5;
}

.active {
  background-color: #a62c21;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Nav-Items *** */

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ***   START: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->

    <nav class="navigation">

      <!-- *** START: Logo *** -->
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="src/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Logo *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-Center *** -->
      <div class ="nav-center nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-Center *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-End *** -->
      <div class="nav-end nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-End *** -->

    </nav>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *** END: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->






  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't put your `.nav-logo img` as absolute

Comment: Why shouldn't I do that?

Answer (score 3):

remove  `height: 100%;` from your div element on the line 41 of your css , and for the horizental center , you need to have a width for your container
I did edit your css to have 49% widht on your right nav and 50% on your left nav to be able to center it , another alternative is to use `flex`

```css
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/************************************************************* styles.css ***************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:General Settings *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:General Settings  *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navigation > div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/* *** START: Nav-Logo *** */
nav div.nav-logo img {
  height: 3rem;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left:2rem;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Logo *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Center *** */
nav .nav-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 50%;
}

nav .nav-center > ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Center *** */


/* *** START: Nav-End *** */
div.nav-end {
  float:right;
  width:49%;
}
/* *** END: Nav-End *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Items *** */
div.nav-items ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.nav-items ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

div.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

div.nav-items a:link {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:visited {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:hover,
div.nav-items a:active {
  color:#e5e5e5;
}

.active {
  background-color: #a62c21;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Nav-Items *** */

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ***   START: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->

    <nav class="navigation">

      <!-- *** START: Logo *** -->
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="src/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Logo *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-Center *** -->
      <div class ="nav-center nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-Center *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-End *** -->
      <div class="nav-end nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-End *** -->

    </nav>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *** END: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->






  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not centered 'horizontaly'

Comment: I mean horizontaly centered.

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif you might be mistaking horizontal center for vertical. Aka have it between logo and page1 button with the same amount of space between

Comment: @MateuszJuruś now i get you , I will edit my answear

Comment: @coder007 you need to have a width for the container to be able to center it , I did edit my answear check it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center

```
 .navigation {
    display:flex
 }
 .navigation > div {
   /*height: 100%;*/
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That centers it verticly not horizontaly

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
.navigation{
    text-align:center;
}

.nav-logo{
    float:left;
}

nav .nav-center{
    float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.navigation {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navigation > div {
  height:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/* *** START: Nav-Logo *** */
nav div.nav-logo img {
  height: 3rem;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left:2rem;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Logo *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Center *** */
nav .nav-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

nav .nav-center > ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Center *** */


/* *** START: Nav-End *** */
div.nav-end {
  float:right;
}
/* *** END: Nav-End *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Items *** */
div.nav-items ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.nav-items ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

div.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

div.nav-items a:link {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:visited {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:hover,
div.nav-items a:active {
  color:#e5e5e5;
}

.active {
  background-color: #a62c21;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Nav-Items *** */

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
</style>

<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ***   START: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->

    <nav class="navigation">

      <!-- *** START: Logo *** -->
      <div class="nav-logo" style="float: left; text-align: center; width: 50%">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="src/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Logo *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-Center *** -->
      <div class ="nav-center nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-Center *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-End *** -->
      <div class="nav-end nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-End *** -->

    </nav>


  </body>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: It is not centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below css

```
nav div.nav-logo img {
  height: 3rem;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left:2rem;
}
```

And add below css

```
nav div.nav-logo a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/************************************************************* styles.css ***************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:General Settings *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:General Settings  *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation > div {
  height:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/* *** START: Nav-Logo *** */
nav div.nav-logo img {
  /*height:3rem;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left:2rem; */
}
nav div.nav-logo a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Logo *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Center *** */
nav .nav-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

nav .nav-center > ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Center *** */


/* *** START: Nav-End *** */
div.nav-end {
  float:right;
}
/* *** END: Nav-End *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Items *** */
div.nav-items ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.nav-items ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

div.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

div.nav-items a:link {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:visited {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:hover,
div.nav-items a:active {
  color:#e5e5e5;
}

.active {
  background-color: #a62c21;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Nav-Items *** */

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ***   START: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->

    <nav class="navigation">

      <!-- *** START: Logo *** -->
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="src/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Logo *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-Center *** -->
      <div class ="nav-center nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-Center *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-End *** -->
      <div class="nav-end nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-End *** -->

    </nav>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *** END: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->






  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it's not horizontally centered.

Comment: That isn't centered. I've used Photosop to check that. f I remove the code under nav div.nav-logo img then my image is scaled wrong. And the code nav div.nav-logo a { vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; } had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In line 27 of your HTML-Document you wrote "div class = "nav -center nav-items"", so I think this is where the better part of your problem is located. Since both HTML and CSS are kind of strict you will have to add a class with that exact name into your CSS. (Sorry if I just didn't see it)

After that you should try again with margin and/or padding. Also please check if the position of your element is fixed or relative. because if it is fixed it will always stay at it´s original position, while when it´s relative you get to decide where to put it and it´ll for exp. slide if the user decides to scroll down or narrow the window. So you might have to fix that as well.

Maybe it helps you to imagine your navbar like a table. Within a table you can define each row, column or cell with specific attributes. So if you look at a navbar you can not only define the navbar itself but also your divs as they are part of your navbar. So for example you could say:

```
.navbar{

         width: 90%;
}
```

If you have three divs for example, you have to 'match' them with the navbar. so just split it´s width (in this case) into three:

```
.navbardiv1 {
         width: 30%;
}

.navbardiv2 {
        width: 30%;
}

.navbardiv3 {
        width: 30%
}
```

Also you can let your divs float left, right or center.

```
.navbardiv1 {
       float: left;
}

.navbardiv2 {
      float: center;
}

.navbardiv3 {
       float: right;
}
```

I hope that this will help you solve your problem and that I understood your correctly, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Updated css in

```
nav .nav-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/************************************************************* styles.css ***************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:General Settings *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:General Settings  *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** START:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navigation > div {
  height:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/* *** START: Nav-Logo *** */
nav div.nav-logo img {
  height: 3rem;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left:2rem;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Logo *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Center *** */
nav .nav-center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

nav .nav-center > ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Center *** */


/* *** START: Nav-End *** */
div.nav-end {
  float:right;
}
/* *** END: Nav-End *** */


/* *** START: Nav-Items *** */
div.nav-items ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.nav-items ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

div.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

div.nav-items a:link {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:visited {
  color:#fff;
}

div.nav-items a:hover,
div.nav-items a:active {
  color:#e5e5e5;
}

.active {
  background-color: #a62c21;
}
/* *** END: Nav-Nav-Items *** */

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
/* *** END:Navigation *** */
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ***   START: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->

    <nav class="navigation">

      <!-- *** START: Logo *** -->
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="src/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Logo *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-Center *** -->
      <div class ="nav-center nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-Center *** -->


      <!-- *** START: Nav-End *** -->
      <div class="nav-end nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- *** END: Nav-End *** -->

    </nav>

    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- *** END: Navigation *** -->
    <!-- **************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->






  </body>
</html>
```